# How to batch transactions?

Tags: baking, transactions

How do I send a single operation that contains multiple transactions in order to do batch payments?

Answer (score 8):

https://kukai.app (not for mobile)

You can use the kukai wallet to do multi-send operations. It was a feature-request from a baker and now multiple bakers are using it.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a good reference article by one baker on the topic

[Sending multiple transactions in one batch using tezos rpc](https://medium.com/@bakenrolls/sending-multiple-transactions-in-one-batch-using-tezos-rpc-6cab3a21f254)